# Image appears before paragraph

Tags: floats, positioning

A part of my document looks like this:

```
\paragraph{blah}

 \begin{figure}[ht!] 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{3a.jpg} 
\caption{(a)}    
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!] 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{3b.jpg} 
\caption{(b)} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht!] 
\centering 
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{3c.jpg} 
\caption{(c)} 
\end{figure}
```

and image 3a shows before the 'blah' paragraph heading. Why is it doing that and how do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By specifying `[ht!]` for the position of each figure, you are insisting that LaTeX place your figure either `h`ere (current position) or at the `t`op of the page. It decides that the top of the page is the best option, and places the figure there. Please see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8653/21344) for details on float position specification.