# Putting Figures Side-By-Side Using Minipage

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I am trying to put two figures next to each other. However, it is not working. Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{prob1_6_2}
\caption{$dt=0.1$}
\label{fig:prob1_6_2}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{prob1_6_1}
\caption{$dt =$}
\label{fig:prob1_6_1}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
```

In my preamble I have `\usepackage{minipage}`. But it hasn't worked. And yes, I have searched through other posts.

Comment: You have a break (empty line and whitespace) in between the `minipage` environments. Remove the empty line and place `%` after the first `\end{minipage}`. Also, you cannot place two `minipage`s side-by-side if each one is the width of the typeblock. No extra package is required for `minipage`; it is a standard environment.

Comment: @PaulGessler Okay, thank you. What should I change the width to?

Comment: If you want the two `minipage`s to span the width of the text area, the *sum* of their widths should be `1.0\textwidth`. The specific values depend on the size of the figures and how you'd like them arranged. Check the link in @cmhughes comment for more details.

Comment: also don't use `[h]` on its own it makes it highly likely the float goes to the end of the document latex will usually warn and change it to `[ht]` to give itself a chance , but best to include p as well: `[thp]`

Comment: Also, no line break between the `minipage` environments.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Blank lines tell `LaTeX` to start a new paragraph, which is one of the reasons that your code puts the figures on their own lines; the other reason is that the sum of the width of your two `minipage`s  is `2\textwidth`, which is wider than `\textwidth`.

There are a few things that we can do to fix this:

- remove the blank line between the first `\end{minipage}` and the second `\begin{minipage}...`
- change the `width` argument of each `minipage` so that the combined width is less than or equal to `\textwidth`; of course, if you'd prefer to overflow the page margins, then you can crank it up higher
- add a `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` which removes the little bit of horizontal space that is automatically inserted by the `minipage` environment.

Referring to this line of your code:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{prob1_6_2}
```

This will refer to the *current* `linewidth`, i.e, the width of the current `minipage` in which it resides. If we make each `minipage` have a width of `.5\textwidth`, then the width of this graphic will actually be `.15\textwidth` wide. Adjust as you see fit- typically, I specify the width of the `minipage`, and then prefer to use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth...`

Finally, there are some concerns about using `\begin{figure}[h]`. Float placement has been discussed in great detail at the following links (in order of recommended reading- the last one is *epic*):

- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)
- [What does [t] and [ht] mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/what-does-t-and-ht-mean)
- [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Here is a complete (modified) version of your code that implements the changes described above.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{prob1_6_2}
        \caption{$dt=0.1$}
        \label{fig:prob1_6_2}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{prob1_6_1}
        \caption{$dt =$}
        \label{fig:prob1_6_1}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

For further options about putting figures side by side, have a look at [LaTeX figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side) and the links within- there are a *lot* of options available.

My final comment is to consider using descriptive labels- using `\label{fig:prob1_6_1}` is ok, but it doesn't tell you much about what the `figure` actually shows you. This may not matter when you're writing the document and you are intimately familiar with it, but if you come back to it at a later time, you might wish for more details; for example, if the figure shows solution to a `Bernoulli` equation , you might label it `fig:bernoulli`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "add a `%` after the first `\end{minipage}` which removes the little bit of horizontal space that is automatically inserted by the minipage environment." Adding that `%` simply removes the end-line character that LaTeX would convert to a space. The `minipage` doesn't automatically insert any space on its own, regardless of what follows `\end{minipage}`.

Comment: @Dan thanks for the clarification- I'll updated later today

Comment: Is there any possibilities of arranging the figure anywhere we want.???

Comment: @David I'm afraid I don't understand your question... could you clarify?

Comment: @cmhughes In reference to Davids question, I am having the same issue. I would like the figure to show up precisely there it is in my TeX document. This figure shows up at the top of the next page. Thanks.

Comment: I imagine you're using a figure environment, try removing it

Answer (score -1):

This problem may be due to larger subcaption text. Reduce the length of subcaption and your problem will be solved.

Comment: It should work with different sized captions as well (I, for one, do it rather often).