# How to put figures in two column horizontally and not vertically in top and bottom?

Tags: floats

How to put figures in two column horizontally and not vertically in top and bottom? can you bring an example?

Comment: are the figures the width of the full page?  if so, then the `figure*` (or `table*`) environment is what you want; those can go only at the top of a page.  some tactics for full-width bottom insertions are given in an answer to [How to put a full-width table at the top or bottom of the same two-column page as the reference text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107430).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite unspecific, but one example could be to choose the size of the figures to be smaller than half the columnwidth.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is two figures side by side. If you need more flexibility, consider [Putting Figures Side-By-Side Using Minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157222/putting-figures-side-by-side-using-minipage) where the `minipage` environment is used:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

As an alternative, you can use `subbottom` for subfloats in `memoir` or the `subfigure` package for subfigures in other documentclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Your question just helped me solve my problem.

I was trying to put text and figure in one row of a table and could not get it to work.  After reading your question, I tried the following to get my figure on right (and text on left).

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

The image to the right represents a 

\begin{enumerate}  
\item tree  
\item graph 
\end{enumerate} 

\vfill
\columnbreak

\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{image.png}

\end{multicols}
```

Maybe my solution will help you get one image in one column and the other in the second column?  I would guess that the images must be same (or close) to same size.  Use the \vfill and \columnbreak to help force the layout you want.