# How to correctly right align text within minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins, minipage

Right-aligned text within the `minipage` environment is too far to the right; how can I align to the right but keep within the boundary so it does not go further to the right than the `\rule` below.

## Code

```
% Define document class, font size
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

% Tweak page margins
% Set left and right margin and compute the remaining ones
% https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins#!#Paper_size.2C_orientation_and_margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={170mm,257mm},
    left=20mm,
    top=20mm}
% --

% Disable paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Multicolumn section
\usepackage{multicol}

% Do not show the section numbers
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

% Load xcolor package and define colours
\usepackage{xcolor}
% \definecolor{darkcerulean}{rgb}{0.03, 0.27, 0.49}
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}
% --

% Define PDF metadata and link colours
\usepackage[pdfauthor={person},
            pdfcreator={vim},
        colorlinks={true}, % colour hyperlinks according to settings
        allcolors={linkcolour}
        ]{hyperref}
% --

\begin{document}  

% Place details side-by-side using minipage placeholder
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157246/123504

% Minipage with 
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    {\Large\textbf{A} \par} 
    text $\cdot$ text $\cdot$ text $\cdot$ text \\
    text
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.5cm}
% Another minipage
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushright}
        \textit{A} \href{https://www.google.com/}{This is too far to the right}
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

% Draw rule spanning the text width
% Add space (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/123504)
\enspace
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

%  Summary section
\section{Summary}

% Multi-column summary section
\begin{multicols}{2}
    This will be in a new column, here is some text without a meaning.  This text
    should show what a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there
    no information?  Is there...
\end{multicols}

% Other section
\section{Something}

\end{document}
```

## Preview

[image]

Comment: i removed the "align" tag because that's specifically for the multi-line display math environment `align`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account the `\hspace{0.5cm}` between the two minipages, and add `%` at the end of lines, to prevent some unwanted `\space`s, like this:

```
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    {\Large\textbf{A} \par}
    text $\cdot$ text $\cdot$ text $\cdot$ text \\
    text
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.5cm}%
% Another minipage
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-0.5cm}
    \begin{flushright}
        \textit{A} \href{https://www.google.com/}{This is too far to the right}
    \end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]