# How can I adjust this tikzpicture to my a4 page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikzpeople

How can I adjust this tikzpicture to my a4 page? I write this after my paragraph. But it goes to before my title, to the top of my page.

```
 \documentclass{ltxdoc}
    \usepackage[demo]{tikzpeople}
    \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[title]{appendix}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
    \begin{document}
\section{Commintment} 
//explanation some
\begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
                    \node[alice,minimum size=1.5cm] (A) {};
                    \node[bob,right=3cm of A,minimum size=1.5cm,mirrored] (B) {};
                    \node[anchor=north east] at (A.north west) (a2) {$(\mathsf{com},\mathsf{dec}) \gets \mathsf{Com}(a)$};
                    \node[anchor=south] at (a2.north) (a1) {$a\gets\{0,1\}$};
                    \node[anchor=south west] at (B.south east){$a \gets \mathsf{Opn}(\mathsf{com},\mathsf{dec})$};
                    \draw (A.35) edge[->] node[above] {$\mathsf{com}$} (B.145);
                    \node[anchor=south west] at (B.east |- B.180) {$b\gets\{0,1\}$};
                    \draw (A.0) edge[<-] node[above] {$b$} (B.180);
                    \draw (A.325) edge[->] node[above] {$\mathsf{dec}$} (B.215);
                    \draw (A.270) ++(0,-.5) node {$a\oplus b$} edge[<-] (A.270);
                    \draw (B.270) ++(0,-.5) node {$a\oplus b$} edge[<-] (B.270);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{A secure coin flipping protocol constructed from bit commitment.}
                \label{fig:protocolexample}
            \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a compilable code, which starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Those trying to help you will need this information.

Comment: You're doing something non-standard. By default, LaTeX won't put a float at the top of a page with `\maketitle`.

Comment: What placement specifier do you use in the figure environment? If you use `\begin{figure}[t!]...\end{figure}`, then obviously the figure will be at the top of the page.

Comment: Give some placement specifier, i.e. `\begin{figure}[htbp]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some placement specifiers to your figures. See for instance the detailed answer here: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) 
 or here: [What does [t] and [ht] mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/what-does-t-and-ht-mean)

If you just remove the `figure` environment you will not be able to add captions and labels. In your MWE, I added the `[ht]` placement, which  will try to put the figure at the insertion point or on the top of the next page.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
    \usepackage[demo]{tikzpeople}
    \usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{xspace}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[title]{appendix}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}
\section{Commintment} 
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
                    \node[alice,minimum size=1.5cm] (A) {};
                    \node[bob,right=3cm of A,minimum size=1.5cm,mirrored] (B) {};
                    \node[anchor=north east] at (A.north west) (a2) {$(\mathsf{com},\mathsf{dec}) \gets \mathsf{Com}(a)$};
                    \node[anchor=south] at (a2.north) (a1) {$a\gets\{0,1\}$};
                    \node[anchor=south west] at (B.south east){$a \gets \mathsf{Opn}(\mathsf{com},\mathsf{dec})$};
                    \draw (A.35) edge[->] node[above] {$\mathsf{com}$} (B.145);
                    \node[anchor=south west] at (B.east |- B.180) {$b\gets\{0,1\}$};
                    \draw (A.0) edge[<-] node[above] {$b$} (B.180);
                    \draw (A.325) edge[->] node[above] {$\mathsf{dec}$} (B.215);
                    \draw (A.270) ++(0,-.5) node {$a\oplus b$} edge[<-] (A.270);
                    \draw (B.270) ++(0,-.5) node {$a\oplus b$} edge[<-] (B.270);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \caption{A secure coin flipping protocol constructed from bit commitment.}
                \label{fig:protocolexample}
            \end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
    \end{document}
```