# Positioning figure with [htb] vs [htbp]?

Tags: floats, miktex, texmaker

I'm very new to Latex, I'm using MiKTeX with Texmaker on Windows.

When I execute the following code I get the desired result:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\label{fig:MagEngT}

\centering 

\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{MagEngTemp.png}  
\caption{Words and such}

\end{figure}

\paragraph{}

Yet more words
```

[image: Correct]

However, if I instead choose to position the figure with [htbp] it has some kind of emotional breakdown and sits in the middle of the page by itself, pushing the paragraph below onto the next page.

My understanding was that by using [htbp] I was indicating a preference in position, so I don't see why adding the p explicitly, since, as far as I know, it defaults to that when it's out of options anyway, changes the behaviour? More to the point, why does it change the behaviour to sitting in the middle of a blank page with occupied pages above and below? I thought it was supposed to float to an empty page at the end of the document?

Any help understanding this is appreciated. :)

Also, I just noticed I've made some spelling errors, aha.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8653/224762) you will find an explanation what these parameters will do.

Comment: Yes, this is how I thought they worked. Maybe I'm just tired, but this doesn't really explain why explicitly stating that it can fall back to "p" if [htb] all fail, causes it to do this?

Comment: It does not fall back to `p` if no `p` is present in the `[...]` list. Normally a new chapter starts with a `\clear(double)page` which additionally dumps all unprocessed floats before proceeding. Placement via `[htb]` will fail if the image is of a certain size and will thus keep being pushed on and on taking the rest of the queue with it until the document ends or a clearpage if found.