# LaTeX shoves Text from newer sections inbetween the tables from previous chapters

Tags: tables, sectioning

I have a subsection primarily consisting of 6 tables. After compiling, the compiler shoves the headline and some text from the next subsection after the 3rd table. This next subsection also has a table, and for whatever reason it shows up inbetween some text and figures of the next section. There placement is always defined as "[!h]", and i've tried varous combinations of \newpage \newline and \pagebreak and nothing seems to solve the issue.
Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: First: Using `[h!]` is not recommended. It is to much limiting the float mechanism. Usually you should at least add `p` to allow float pages. Second: `\newpage` does not force the output of float, nor does `\newline` or `\pagebreak`. You'd need to use `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`). Third: If you don't want tables (or figured) to float, don't use `table` (and `figure`).

Comment: And see also the note about using `!` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8653/277964) and also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9485/277964).

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers, the \floatbarrier command from the \usepackage{placeins} package was exactly what i was looking for!